# Firebird SQL - Convert decimal Long Lat co-oords to Deg mins secs

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a longitude and latitude column stored in table that I need to convert using SQL. The database is Firebird.

Values are 31.22027777777778 and -29.53805555555556 respectively.

My output should be

```
Longitude
E 31 deg 13 min 13.00 sec

Latitude 
S 29 deg 32 min 17.00 sec
```

Of course this should check for positive decimals on Latitude which would translate to 'N' instead of 'S'  etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67115/how-to-convert-geometry-type-column-to-degree-minutes-second-in-sql-server-2008. Of course replace geom type `@geom.STX` and `@geom.STY` with your columns

Comment: [Quick demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/402470) You should be able to translate it to Firebird.

Comment: @lad2025 thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based on [`How to convert Geometry type column to degree Minutes Second in SQL Server 2008 R2`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67115/how-to-convert-geometry-type-column-to-degree-minutes-second-in-sql-server-2008):

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(longitude DECIMAL(38,18), latitude DECIMAL(38,18));

INSERT INTO #tab
VALUES (31.22027777777778 , -29.53805555555556);


SELECT longitude, latitude, CAST(FLOOR(ABS(longitude)) as varchar) + ' ' +
    CAST(CAST(FLOOR(ABS(longitude) * 60) AS INT) % 60 as varchar) + ''' ' +
    CAST(CAST(FLOOR(ABS(longitude) * 3600) AS INT) % 60 AS VARCHAR) + '"' +
    CASE WHEN longitude < 0 then ' W' ELSE ' E' END,
  CAST(FLOOR(ABS(latitude)) as varchar) + ' ' +
    CAST(CAST(FLOOR(ABS(latitude) * 60) AS INT) % 60 as varchar) + ''' ' +
    CAST(CAST(FLOOR(ABS(latitude) * 3600) AS INT) % 60 AS VARCHAR) + '"' +
    CASE WHEN latitude < 0 then ' S' ELSE ' N' END 
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/402470)**</kbd>

There are used basic numeric operations like `modulo division/FLOOR/ABS`. I think you will be able to translate it for `Firebird` dialect.

**Bonus `SQLServer2012+`:**

```
SELECT 
 longitude,
 latitude, 
 [longitude_dms] = FORMATMESSAGE('%i %i'' %i.00" %s',
                                CAST(FLOOR(ABS(longitude)) AS INT),
                                CAST(FLOOR(ABS(longitude) * 60) AS INT) % 60,
                                CAST(FLOOR(ABS(longitude) * 3600) AS INT) % 60,
                                IIF(longitude < 0, 'W', 'E')),
 [latitude_dms] = FORMATMESSAGE('%i %i'' %i.00" %s',
                                CAST(FLOOR(ABS(latitude)) AS INT),
                                CAST(FLOOR(ABS(latitude) * 60) AS INT) % 60,
                                CAST(FLOOR(ABS(latitude) * 3600) AS INT) % 60,
                                IIF(latitude < 0, 'S', 'N'))
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/402512)**</kbd>